# How to switch physics body type in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, game-physics

I have a kinematic body in my game that I switch to a dynamic body when it needs to jump so the physics simulation can handle all the complexities of gravity. I do this by replacing the *entire* physics body of the node. However, doing this also resets all the customisation you can do to physics bodies. Is there any way to change the physics body of a node without creating a new one? Or at least a way that somehow “copies” all the values like restitution, angular dampening, etc.

What I’ve tried so far:

1. Changing the `type` property on a physics body but the documentation says it’s supposed to be a constant (even though it’s a get-set property???). I don’t want to go against the documentation so I don’t think this should be the right way
2. Experimenting with pointers and reflections to copy the values somehow. I started reading about `Mirror` yesterday so I’m not sure if functionality like this even would be possible, but I am considering it.
3. Using the `copy()` function, however, I’d still have to manually copy all the small settings

Please let me know if there’s a way to switch the physics body type while preserving its properties such as bitmasks, physics settings, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a `SCNPhysicsBody` consists of its own "constructed" geometry, you will need to recreate it each time you want to change it. But you could i.Ex. predefine all `physicsBodies` you need (dynamic, static, kinematic, including all properties like bitmasks, etc...) in a set of variables or constants and then you assign the one you want at the moment you need it.